# Scala get value from lambda

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

I want to get value from function that passed as parameter and returns Option[Int], after that if I have None throw an exception and in any other case return value
I tried to do like this:

```
def foo[T](f: T => Option[Int]) = {
   def helper(x: T) = f(x)
   val res = helper _
   res match {
       case None => throw new Exception()
       case Some(z) => z
}
```

I call it like this:

```
val test = foo[String](myFunction(_))
test("Some string")
```

I have compilation error with mismatched types in match section (Some[A] passed - [T] => Option[Int] required)
As I understood res variable is reference to the function and I cannot match it with optional either call get\gerOrElse methods. 
Moreover I probably just dont get how the underscore works and doing something really wrong, I'm using it here to pass a something as parameter to function f, can you explain me where I made a mistake?

Comment: sorry, can't edit question, after val test = .... I also call the test with some parameters like test("aaaa")

Comment: You *can* edit the question. There's an edit button underneath it.

Comment: What does the  signature of `myFunction` look like? It seems like it doesn't match what the input to `foo` wants.

Comment: You say you want an `Option[Int]` output. What `Int` value do you expect for a given input?

Comment: @Tanjin def myFunction(digits: String): Option[Int] =
  if(digits.matches("[0-9]*")) Some(digits.toInt) else None

Comment: @jwvh Int number from string

Comment: What `Int` **value**? 5? 72? For what string input? "blahblah"? "xxx"?

Comment: @jwvh For any number string - get corresponding int number, for non-numeric string - None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helper` is a method taking a `T` and returning an `Option[Int]`.

`res` is a function `T => Option[Int]`.

[Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

You can't match a function `T => Option[Int]` with `None` or `Some(z)`.

You should have an `Option[Int]` (for example the function applied to some `T`) to make such matching.

Probably you would like to have

```
  def foo[T](f: T => Option[Int]) = {
    def helper(x: T) = f(x)
    val res = helper _
    (t: T) => res(t) match {
      case None => throw new Exception()
      case Some(z) => z
    }
  }
```

or just

```
  def foo[T](f: T => Option[Int]): T => Int = {
    t => f(t) match {
      case None => throw new Exception()
      case Some(z) => z
    }
  }
```

or

```
  def foo[T](f: T => Option[Int]): T => Int = 
    t => f(t).getOrElse(throw new Exception())
```